# Инструменты реализации клиент-серверной модели для мобильного приложения

Tags: java, android, клиент-сервер

Доброго времени суток всем. Просмотрел схожие топики с моим вопросом, дельного ничего не нашел. Суть такая, хочу поэкспериментировать с написанием клиент-серверного приложения, в составе которого будет клиент(мобильное приложение android) и сервер(все будет написано на Java). Вопрос в следующем, какие для этого инструменты, технологии нужны? Достаточно ли будет на стороне сервера поднять CentOS + Tomcat + postgreSQL и на стороне клиента мобильное приложение из пары активити, которое будет отображать какие-то данные(например, новости), полученные с сервера. Перечень описанных инструментов и технологий не принципиален, предлагайте свои варианты с обоснованием, буду очень признателен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451868/adding-a-database-backend-to-android-applications) сказано, как должен быть организован Backend для мобильного приложения. Набор инструментов можно оставить тот же.